# Silicon and Germanium semiconductors mixture in quantum computing

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, machine-learning

Can Silicon and Germanium semiconductors mixture (chemical reaction) with some other chemical elements (if required) assist in creating new and existing robust electronic components?

Si + Ge + ? + ? =

Can this mixture assist in quantum computing?

Comment: What do you know of semiconductor fabrication? SiGe is a common lattice used in source/drain/channel engineering, and may have some advantages in carrier mobility/strain.  But are you asking about use in particular, in, say, superconducting qubits?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes. Possible other elements mixed together could be gallium, arsenide etc with silicon, germanium.

Comment: https://youtu.be/uPw9nkJAwDY

Answer (score 1):

I would  say that rather an alloy of the mentioned elements than their chemical compound can be used in quantum processors fabrication. Generally, superconducting qubits are based on silicon. However, there were some attempts to use germanium as it seems that Ge provides better coherence times. See this article for further information: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04268.